# p:ajax not working with p:commandButton

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I try to do this but I never get it work ;why is that ajax not supported ??

```
<p:commandButton value="MAJ" rendered="#{LigneXL.resultat eq 'Pas de FMD'}" onclick="confirmation.show()"  >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{parserXls.selectitem}" value="#{LigneXL}" />                  
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{parserXls.listenercomposant()}"/>             
</p:commandButton>
```

Listener is never executed Why !!!
I'm trying to get another object according to selectitem

```
public void listenercomposant(){
    composantitem=ChercherComposant(selcetitem.getRefcomposant(), selcetitem.getReffabricant());
}
```

Comment: I hope *selcetitem* is correctly spelled in your real code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `p:commandButton` is already natively [ajax enabled](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml). So there is no need to have a `p:ajax` inside and and you can just use

```
  <p:commandButton value="TestButton" actionListener="#{bean.saveSomething}" id="id"    
  update="panel" />
```

As you can see `p:commandButton` already has and actionListener so just use that.

Comment: Yes I try to use this ,but when I used the selectitem is not updating beacuse set Property is executed after action listner

Comment: selectitem is null when I'm using actionListner

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly you are trying to do?
What kinda scenario you are dealing with?

Comment: I'm working on data table every ligne has button .when I click button  I whloud changing somme property for this ligne this why I'm using setpropertyActionListener .but also I ned to get other obejct according to this selectitem

Comment: Accept as Answer then please.

Comment: what was the problem to this question? I am having some similar problems

Answer (score -2):

this is the solution I use action instead of listener

```
  <p:commandButton value="MAJ" rendered="#{LigneXL.resultat eq 'Pas de FMD'}" onclick="confirmation.show()" action="#{parserXls.listenercomposant()}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{parserXls.selcetitem}" value="#{LigneXL}" />                                            
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: This doesn't use ajax.

Comment: @GregD:  it does…  ajax is built-in in this component

Comment: @Kukeltje Indeed it is. Wasn't aware of that when I was posting this comment more than a year ago.